# как правильно обойти древовидный объект при помощи рекурсии с сохранением результата вычислений

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

дан объект:

```
const o = {
    a: 2,
    b: {
      a: 3,
      b: 4,
      c: {
        a: 5,
        b: 6
      }
    },
    c: 1
  }
```

необходимо написать функцию которая сложит все значения свойств объекта при помощи рекурсии.

При этом, нельзя использовать начальное значение в качестве аргумента функции. Не получается сделать это без переменной в глобальной области видимости и нет идей, как вообще может быть выполнена эта задача в коде. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const o = { a: 2, b: { a: 3, b: 4, c: { a: 5, b: 6 } }, c: 1 };

function sum() {
  var result = 0;
  for (var key in this) {
    if (typeof this[key] == "number")
      result += this[key];
    else
      result += sum.call(this[key]);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(sum.call(o));
```

```js
const o = { a: 2, b: { a: 3, b: 4, c: { a: 5, b: 6 } }, c: 1 };

Object.prototype.sum = function() {
  var result = 0;
  for (var key in this) {
    if (typeof this[key] == "number")
      result += this[key];
    else if (typeof this[key] == "object")
      result += sum.call(this[key]);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(o.sum());
```

Comment: @AlexandrShmidt Пожалуйста. С радостью бы порекомендовал бы что-нибудь, но меня такие вопросы всегда ставят в тупик. Я обычно в результате поисков оказываюсь на MDN. Правда, на английском.

Comment: понял, буду штудировать

Comment: @AlexandrShmidt Успехов! Вы, главное, не забывайте принимать ответы на Ваши вопросы ) - знак "галочка" слева от ответа.